# Gallstones pain relief?

Tags: pain, gallbladder, gastroenterology

What suggestions are there for pain relief caused by stones in the gallbladder, while waiting for surgery date?

Placing something cold as an ice bag on the area, reduces the pain, and that helps, but any other recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If your abdomen pain in the upper right quadrant have been diagnosed as gall bladder stones and you are awaiting for surgery, I am very puzzled that you have not received a prescription for appropriate pain relief medication.

In Finland the drug of choice is Litalgin, which contains metamizole and pitophenone. The former is a pain killer and the latter is muscle relaxant which affects directly to smooth muscle tissues located in GI and urinary tract. It is also very good medication for kidney stones.

Another good medication for gallbladder stones is any fast acting NSAID.

You should contact your GP or treating surgeon for appropriate medication.

Answer (score -1):

Use a heat pack or heating pad. For immediate relief, apply a hot water bottle, heating pad, or other heat pack to your stomach, directly over the gallbladder. The heat should help soothe the pain.
If you do not have a heating pad or hot pack, you could also try soaking in a hot bath.

A pain reliever with anti-inflammatory properties will be best since it can ease your pain while also restricting the amount of inflammation your gallbladder experiences

Drink apple cider vinegar in water or apple juice to help relieve pain due to an attack. Apple cider vinegar also reduces cholesterol produced by the liver.

Drink vegetable juice – not the premixed cocktail versions, but pure juice from vegetables.

Rub castor oil over your abdomen, especially where your gallbladder is located.

Drink salt water. Mix coarse salt into a glass of warm water and drink the water before going to sleep to help loosen painful buildup in your gallbladder.

You can get more info here: 
[Home Treatment for Gallbladder Pain](http://www.wikihow.com/Ease-Gallbladder-Pain)
[Home remedies and diet for gallstones](http://www.belmarrahealth.com/gallstones-cholelithiasis-risk-increases-with-high-bmi-rapid-weight-loss/)